# start iPad application from another application built in Flash

Tags: flash, ipad, flash-builder

Do you know is it possible to start iPad application from another application that is developed in Flash?
I need to create small iPad app with two buttons (and some graphics/animation) in Flash. Clicking on those buttons, another iPad application should be started.

My guess is that will use ExternallInterface, but I don't know what to send :)
Thank you!

Comment: You are aware of the fact that there is no flash on the iPad, right?

Comment: @hop: There is no support for Flash (or other plugins or applets) in the web browser on iOS devices, but Flash/Flex/ActionScript can be used to develop iOS apps: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/ios.html

Comment: ah, flash builder. that's another story. who's using that anyway? should have mentioned that in the question, too.

Comment: Thank you @robin! URL scheme is what I needed. I'm developing app in Flash but build it for iOS. @hop, I use Flash Professional CS5.5 actually, sorry not to mention that in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to launch another app from your app then you can do it using URL Scheme provided by apple

Here is the documentation on this one http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html

And a useful link that gives url scheme for most of the apps available out there.

http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/find-ios-custom-url-schemes-from-thousands-of-apps-and-add-yours/